# Objective C General Print

Tags: objective-c

Does objective C have a general print command like Python? NSLog seems to log it rather than print out to console. printf only accepts specific types.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`NSLog()` does print to the console, and is very similar to C's `printf()`.  Having its origins and basis in C, console printing is done as it is in C, essentially.

Comment: Was about to say the same thing! +1

Comment: Oh, I left out the @ - still new to objective C

Comment: (Was testing it with a string)

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", myObject); will achieve the desired goal.

Answer (score 6):

`printf` is what you're looking for.  You can use it like a regular print statement:

```
printf("This is a neat command!\n");
```

You're also probably aware that you can use it with substitutions:

```
printf("The Answer is %d\n", 42);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `NSString` to format strings containing id types as well as the standard printf types, then just print it using printf:

```
NSString *fmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My formatted string: %@", anObject];

printf("%s", [fmt cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]);
```

Comment: It should be `printf("%s",[fmt cStringUsingEncoding:…])`, to cover the case where the string already has a '%' in it.